# Link to open FancyBox on another page?

Tags: html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a website that is basically a webstore selling items.

On my homepage, I have a some links that refer to specific products. On my shop page, I have image thumbnails of each product that open in FancyBox windows.

I want the links on my homepage to direct customers to the shop page and then open that specific product in its FancyBox window. Is there a way to do this?

I tried giving the FancyBox anchor an ID and then linking to shop.html#product but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use GET variables from PHP to transmit data to the new page. You will transmit that you want fancybox open like this:

```
www.YOUR_DOMAIN.com/YOUR_PAGE?fancybox=true
```

and then the code:

```
<?PHP if (isset($_GET['fancybox'])) { ?>
  <script>
    $("#YOUR_IMAGE_ID").fancybox();
  </script>
<?PHP } ?>
```

I suggest the PHP combination because you might not want the fancybox always open by default. If you do then just add the javascript code:

```
<script>
  $("#YOUR_IMAGE_ID").fancybox();
</script>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: PHP is really outside the realm of necessity for this project. As for the javascript, is there a way to write it so that that link as an onclick event that send the browser to the new page and then opens the fancybox on the new page?

Comment: I don't know any way to transmit data to a new page with just javascript. Sorry.